# How to find the text in label-for of jQuery mobile Radio and Checkbox with knockout?

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox, knockout.js, radio-button, label-for

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1, jQM 1.3 & knockout 2.2.1.

My html is as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" id="coloursView">
    <div data-role="content">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend>Colour:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="colours" data-bind="checked: colour" id="radio-1" value="1" />
            <label for="radio-1">Red</label>
            <input type="radio" name="colours" data-bind="checked: colour" id="radio-2" value="2" />
            <label for="radio-2">Blue</label>
            <input type="radio" name="colours" data-bind="checked: colour" id="radio-3" value="3" />
            <label for="radio-3">Green</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div><!--/content -->
</div><!--/page -->
```

My view model is also very simple:

```
function ColoursViewModel() {
  this.template = "coloursView";
  this.colour = ko.observable("1");
  this.label = ko.observable(); // custom binding
}
```

Now, i would like to get the description of the selected colour, not the value.
It seems to me, that i need a custom binding, like this one:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.label = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $("radio", element).filter(function(el) { return $(el).text() === value; }).prop("checked", "checked");
    }
};
```

But i'm not able to get the text of the related label - the label-for text.

Someone could help? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if i answer myself, but i think i got it. **At least for radio inputs.**

Now, i have a custom binding handler at fieldset level, to keep the markup clean and more readable, as i can:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="front-colours" data-bind="frontColourLabel: frontColour">
    <legend>Front Colour: <span data-bind="text: frontColourDescription"></span> (Value: <span data-bind="text: frontColour"></span>)</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="front-colours" data-bind="checked: frontColour" id="fc-radio-1" value="red" />
    <label for="fc-radio-1">Red</label>
    <input type="radio" name="front-colours" data-bind="checked: frontColour" id="fc-radio-2" value="blue" />
    <label for="fc-radio-2">Blue</label>
    <input type="radio" name="front-colours" data-bind="checked: frontColour" id="fc-radio-3" value="green" />
    <label for="fc-radio-3">Green</label>
</fieldset>
```

this is the binding handler i come up:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.frontColourLabel = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); 
        var id = $('input:radio[name='+element.id+']:checked').prop("id");
        var radioText = $('label[for=' + id + ']').text();
        viewModel.frontColourDescription(radioText);
    }
};
```

the only tricky part here, is that the id of the fieldset is equal to the name of the radio-group, as it's easy to filter out what radio-group i want to address.

**WORKING EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/h7Bmb/1/

I try now to get the checkbox part to work. Someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Here is another approach where to find only `:checked` items and remove *white-space* in text.

> Checkbox

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  var checkbox = $(this).prev('label').text();
  alert('Checkbox: ' + checkbox.replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
 }
});
```

> Radio

```
$('input[type=radio]').each(function () {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  var radio = $(this).prev('label').text();
  alert('Radio: ' + radio.replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
 }
});
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/PedEC/)

---

> Checkbox

```
$('div.ui-checkbox').find('span.ui-btn-text').text();
```

> Radio

```
$('div.ui-radio').find('span.ui-btn-text').text();
```

Comment: wrap the input in a label is valid html, but this is not the case, so I think the trick shall be to find the label through the attribute label-for, something like this
$('label[for='+element.id+']').text());

Comment: Yes its possible, but i just noticed you need the checked ones only. So you need to go through them and pick the checked ones. i'll do another demo. @user2308978

Comment: Thank You Omar, I found out also a change in latest jquery versions, to retrieve the radio, instead of input[radio] it shall be: input[type=radio][name=colours]

Comment: @user2308978 yup `$('input[type=radio][name=colours]')` works.

Comment: @user2308978 i have updated my demo, as text needs to be stripped of white-space. http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/PedEC/

Comment: Hi Omar, thank You for the answer, i have now a fiddle to test more precisely the question:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/MBeU7/
but i'm still not able to get it.
i will put in my knockout nice-to-have-wish-list the label-for binding...

Comment: @user2308978 I understand what you're trying to reach. The text of an input is wrapped by label and two spans, so i dont know how to get it using KOjs. It's easy to manipulate it using jQuery but in KO, i dont whether you can direct it dig deeper into DOM elements. I'm reading about it and hopefully I come up with a solution.